# SQL Statement Case When With Select * Syntax

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL Statement as below:

```
 SELECT * ,(CASE WHEN DRV_ID IS NOT NULL THEN CASE WHEN (DRV_ID)<'100' thenconcat(rental_type_c,'*')ENDELSE '9' end) as testing99FROM dmtb_driver;
```

just wondering why it will prompt me error "From key world no found." If i change my statement in such way:

```
  SELECT DRV_Name,DRV_ID ,(CASE WHEN DRV_ID IS NOT NULL THEN CASE WHEN (DRV_ID)<'100' thenconcat(rental_type_c,'*')ENDELSE '9' end) as testing99FROM dmtb_driver;
```

it working perfectly. Just curious isn't i need to type out all the field name 1 by 1 instead of using '*'?

Comment: What is the data type of DRV_ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alias your table.

```
SELECT
    d.*,
    CASE WHEN DRV_ID IS NOT NULL THEN
       CASE WHEN (DRV_ID)<'100' THEN
           CONCAT(rental_type_c,'*')
       END
    ELSE
        '9'
    END as testing99
FROM
    dmtb_driver d;
```

I think your logic could use some simplification too.

Comment: good suggestion u break it into sub query.i also just found out it can solve using this way.

Answer (score 0):

Ii think you missed space before from and concat, also I don't think so two case statement is required.

```
SELECT * ,(CASE WHEN DRV_ID IS NOT NULL AND (DRV_ID)<'100' then concat(rental_type_c,'*') ELSE '9' end) as testing99 
FROM dmtb_driver;
```